# How to write the thoughts of a character in a drunken POV scene?

Tags: creative-writing, pov, grammatical-person, perspective, altered-perspective

One of my POV characters is an overthinker. Partly because she wishes to stop thinking so much, and partly because of peer pressure, she gets super drunk... and ends up doing something that she would never do in her normal overthinking state.

The reader has become accustomed to reading every one of her excessive thoughts. But how should her thoughts shift as she gets drunk? Should they stop altogether? (e.g., she just does the stupid thing, and the reader has no idea about the thoughts that led up to it) Or, should her thoughts become completely irrational?

Comment: Something similar was asked here, it may be helpful: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/49835/writing-someone-drunk/49842#49842

Comment: Thank you!! Sorry, I didn't see that thread when I was searching!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few options(Some taken from @Sciborg in [this question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/49835/writing-someone-drunk)):

1. Make your character **talk faster**, and a lot **more** about inane things. I usually advise not to add inane greetings into dialogue, but in this case, using weird greetings and farewells could emphasise the drunkenness of the character.
2. **Write irrational and disconnected thoughts**, using sentence fragments and paradoxical statements to showcase the way the character is different to her usual logical self.
3. **Say unusual things.** Does your character swear? Mention sexual relationships? Talk to the other gender? If they don't (for whatever reason, fear, nervousness, etc), then showing them doing this, could exaggerate the drunkenness (especially if the character has before shown their disdain for those who do these things).
4. **Lose motor and visual control.** Seeing auras and bumping into tables, etc can show the drunken state.
5. If your character is really drunk you could **move through the stages of drunkenness** -  euphoria, excitement, confusion and stupor, and show each of them, separately.
6. **See herself as separate to her sober self**, for example, complaining that if "Jennifer", would drink more then "Ava", could party more.

In short, a character who is drunk will **act differently, be more outgoing, daring and less logical, than her normal self.**

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do this is to get drunk yourself. Only then can you really understand.

(Also, this goes with other subjects. You can understand something better when it's happened to you.)

**Edit:** It's important to remember that in certain situations, you should just look it up. Like murder, for example.

Comment: So, the best way to write a crime novel is to commit murder?!? Really? Using research combined with your imagination is a much better choice.

Comment: @RobJarvis No! But that's funny, to be honest. Good thing to point that out lol. Thanks